# j2me polish: showing persian words with error

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

I am developing a j2me polish app,and I used words in Persian(same as Arabic) words. but in some older SonyEricsson phones the words are separated and reversed. I searched the web but I found some topic in LWUIT and not polish. how can I solve my problem in these phones.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices have not `persian font engine` so when you try to show a persian word,you see some problem in arranging of chrarcters and ... .
You have two problems:

1. Separated form of characters.
2. Reversed arranging of characters.

To solve first problem,you can use one of these:

- change the byte code of your App
- use custom font
- use a picture that display the word that you want to show
- use fonts of device(**if device has proper font**)

For more details look at [this link](http://www.hamcodi.ir/qa/questions/487/%D9%85%D8%B4%DA%A9%D9%84-%D8%B2%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-j2me),that I answered some months ago.
To solve second problem,look at [this link](http://www.hamcodi.ir/qa/questions/612/%D8%AA%D8%B4%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%B5-%D9%86%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%87-%DA%86%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%B4-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%DB%8C-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-j2me-%D9%88-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF),I displayed an idea there.

Of course I answer those questions in persian and if you do not know persian,tell me to give you more details.Finally please tell me, if your problem will solved.